# How do I SUM the positive values in a column that also contains #N/A! errors?

Tags: google-sheets

I had trouble getting the SUM of a column that also contained `#N/A!` errors.

I solved it with the following formula

```
=sumif(A1:A20,"<>#N/A")
```

however, I only want to SUM positive values.  When I add `"<0"` I get an error.

How can I modify this formula to only SUM positive values?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add some sample values for A1:A20 and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=sum( iferror( filter(A1:A20, A1:A20 > 0) ) )`